# unattend file not working with any language pack

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, language, language-packs

We have a fully automated system (custom built and not via MDT or anything like that). Anyway, its been working fine for years and now a requirement has ocme in to add some language packs...but, when I inject any language pack into the unattend file I get an error on Windows Setup of "offlinestate incorrect" - or something like that (I forgot to get a screenshot of the issue).

The only thing that is different from the hundreds of servers we build is that this one is injecting in the language pack. I took the unattend file from a broken machine and compared it (via BeyondCompare) to one that works and the only difference is the lines below.

I think there might be some syntax incorrect or something missing? Can anyway one?

Server is Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1. The path of Y:is correct and does exist so not too sure why it is breaking. This happens if I install one language or multiple language as below.

```
<package action="install" permanence="permanent">
<assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft-Windows-Server-LanguagePack-Package" version="6.1.7601.17514" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="es-es" />
<source location="y:\W2K8_R2_SP1_Language_Packs_x64\es-es\lp.cab" />
</package>
<package action="install" permanence="permanent">
<assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft-Windows-Server-LanguagePack-Package" version="6.1.7601.17514" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="fr-fr" />
<source location="y:\W2K8_R2_SP1_Language_Packs_x64\fr-fr\lp.cab" />
</package>
<package action="install" permanence="permanent">
<assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft-Windows-Server-LanguagePack-Package" version="6.1.7601.17514" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="zh-cn" />
<source location="y:\W2K8_R2_SP1_Language_Packs_x64\zh-cn\lp.cab" />
</package>
<package action="install" permanence="permanent">
<assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft-Windows-Server-LanguagePack-Package" version="6.1.7601.17514" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="de-de" />
<source location="y:\W2K8_R2_SP1_Language_Packs_x64\de-de\lp.cab" />
</package>
```

Comment: `I get an error on Windows Setup of "offlinestate incorrect" - or something like that (I forgot to get a screenshot of the issue)` It could be useful though !